# How to force browser to clear cache so changes on my website are shown?

Tags: html, caching

Whenever I make a change on my website I have to clear the cache of my browser so I can see said change. Is there a way to automatize this process? I have seen some similar posts here (suggesting using the cache-control meta tag) but all of them are from years ago, and I would love to get some updated answers. Also, I'm not sure if using those meta tags (eg. ) is the right way, as I've seen some people discouraging their usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add ?xxx to the css and js filenames and browsers will reload them whenever xxx changes.  You won't need to rename your source files.

i.e.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/animations.css?12345678"></link>
```

You may have seen content managers do this, with random strings generated on each session to force a reload on first load, and then cache for the remainder of the session.

Answer (score 1):

If this is regarding .css and .js changes, one way is by appending something like "_versionNum" to the file name for each release. For example:

```
script.css // This is the URL for release 1.0
script_1.1.css // This is the URL for newest release [1.1]
```

You should also refer to this [link](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479551) for more information.